# process A read a file which process B write to

Tags: io

there is 2 process share a file F,the size of each io is a line which is **less than 4k**

- A: read a line from F
- B: write a line to F (append mode)

I want to konw about if the case below will be happen?

**B write half of the line ,then A read from A,and found that eof of F is readed ,and return half of the line.**

Answer (score 0):

At a time, `file` can be used by a single `process` only. If you want it to be shared between two processes, you have to synchronize them. Also, you have to `close` the file before used by second process.